# Random restart technique definition

Tags: algorithms

I have stumbled across this question about the Random restart algorithm in search problems:

Random restart is technique which used for:

a)algorithms for search in space state when they get stuck

b)algorithms for informed search for better solution

c)algorithms for uninformed search for better solution

d)algorithms for local search for better solution

My thoughts are : it's a) or d) but I cannot decide since random restart is used for local search but we don't need better solution, however I haven't found anywhere that random restart helps us getting unstuck?

Comment: An algorithm is stuck when it cannot find a better solution locally. If there is some hope for a yet better solution, a restart is the only way. In a way, a restart is the opposite of a local search.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Computer Science Stack Exchange.

We have two subjects in search algorithms: **Exploration** and **Exploitation**. Now, Random Restart increases Exploration in your search.

There is no guarantee that random restarts help you to find better solutions. But it will give you this chance to search the space solution better.

So, The answer to your question is that random restart doesn't necessarily help us get unstuck. According to the above facts, (**a**) is wrong. Between the other choices, I pick the last one (**d**). I think random restart doesn't belong to informed and uninformed search.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I couldn't understand which answer you have picked. Seems like you have rejected b,c,d because better solution is not found and you rejected a) because it doesn't help get unstuck?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. I hope it's clear now. It seems (a) is the correct answer. @John.L

Answer (score 1):

I could make an argument in favor of both (a) and (d).

If you get stuck, then at some point in the future a random restart will be applied, and then you won't be stuck on the future iteration.  So that's a sense in which (a) could be taken to be true.  On the other hand, within the current iteration, before you apply the random restart, it won't do anything to help you get unstuck, so that's a sense in which (a) could be taken to be false.

Yes, random restarts can be used with local search, and in some/many cases they allow finding a better solution.  So that's a sense in which I view (d) as true.

I am not familiar with the phrases "informed search" or "uninformed search".

Comment: For example BFS is an uninformed search algorithm and Greedy search is an informed search.